# Formatting JSON.stringify code

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have made my callback and now have my hotel list outputted into my browser using JSON.stringify and removed the ugly quotes.

How do I now take only the values I need such as address, hotel name and style these using css?

I can only manage to output the whole callback without any styling

http://www.nelsonbaynsw.com/

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=20&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_AU&city=Sydney&stateProvinceCode=NW&countryCode=AU&numberOfResults=2&type=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback:"myCallback",
    success: function(data) {
        var StrHotelListResponse = data.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary;
        $.each(StrHotelListResponse, function(index, value) {
            var StrHotelListResponse = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#target').append(StrHotelListResponse.replace(/\"/g, ""));  
            $('#target').console.log(JSON.stringify(StrHotelListResponse));
        });
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
        //alert('no');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/XYgbU/

Your success function was almost right, here is the corrected version:

```
success: function(data) {
    var StrHotelListResponse = data.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary;
    $.each(StrHotelListResponse, function(index, value) {
        $('#target').append('<b>Hotel Name:</b> ' + value.name);
        $('#target').append('<br>');
    });
},
```

use the `value` object in the iterator to access each of the individual objects and then you can do what you want to them from there.

So would be value.name, value.city, etc etc. If you use `console.log(value)` you'll be able to see what attributes are available to you.

Hope this helps.